# Dependency not found when trying to inject a generic class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have developed a `GenericDAO` interface with two generic types, the entity and the type of the primary key:

```
public interface GenericDAO<E, PK extends Serializable> {
    PK save(E newInstance);
    void update(E transientObject);
    //typical dao methods
}
```

Then I have provided an implementation for them in hibernate 4:

```
@Transactional
@Component
@Repository
public abstract class GenericDAOHibernate4<E, PK extends Serializable> implements GenericDAO<E, PK> {
    public PK save(E newInstance) {
        return (PK) factory.getCurrentSession().save(newInstance);
    }
    public E findById(PK id) {
        return (E) factory.getCurrentSession().get(getEntityClass(), id);
    }
//method implementations
}
```

Then I just have to create concrete classes extending this abstract class:

```
@Component
@Transactional
@Repository
@Qualifier("userDAO")
public class UserDAO extends GenericDAOHibernate4<User, Long> {

    @Autowired
    public UserDAO(SessionFactory factory) {
        super(factory);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<User> getEntityClass() {
        return User.class;
    }

}
```

Then I inject the concrete DAOs when needed this way:

```
public class UserService extends GenericService<User> {
    @Autowired
    public UserService(@Qualifier("userDAO") GenericDAO<User, Long> dao) {
        super(dao);
    }
```

But, if I need to add another method to the concrete dao, and therefore inject the concrete class, spring cannot find the dependency. This fails at startup:

```
public class UserService extends GenericService<User> {
    @Autowired
    public UserService(@Qualifier("userDAO") UserDAO dao) {
        super(dao);
    }
```

With this error:

> Could not instantiate bean class [ddol.rtdb.services.UserService]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ddol.rtdb.services.UserService.()

How should I inject it?

Comment: How is UserService getting created? Do you have a constructor in GenericService which overrides default constructor?

Comment: It is created using the constructor above, public UserService(@Qualifier("userDAO") UserDAO dao). I have no default constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a class implements an interface, a bean of that class can only be autowired using the interface type and not the concrete class type. Since `UserDao` implements the `GenericDAO<User, Long>` interface, it is being autowired correctly when you autowire using the interface. Spring is not able to find the dependency when you try to autowire using the concrete class, then it looks for a no-arg constructor for `UserService` and fails giving the particular error on not finding any.

In general, it not a good idea to inject dependencies using concrete classes because it tightly couples your modules. Right way to do this is to have an interface for each of your DAO classes and have their implementation extending the `GenericDAOHibernate4`.

```
public interface GenericDAO<E, PK extends Serializable> {
    PK save(E newInstance);
    void update(E transientObject);
    //typical dao methods
}

public interface UserDAO extends GenericDAO<User, Long> {
    List<User> findUsersByFirstname(String firstName);
}

@Component
@Transactional
@Repository
@Qualifier("userDAO")
public class UserDAOImpl extends GenericDAOHibernate4<User, Long> 
        implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    public UserDAO(SessionFactory factory) {
        super(factory);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<User> getEntityClass() {
        return User.class;
    }

    List<User> findUsersByFirstname(String firstName) {
        //provide implementation here
    }

}

public class UserService extends GenericService<User> {
    @Autowired
    public UserService(@Qualifier("userDAO") UserDAO dao) {
        super(dao);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! So the only solution would be to create an interface for each dao object?

Comment: Is it possible to get around this restriction using `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>` (or the equivalent on `@EnableTransactionManagement` in purely annotation-driven config)?

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired = wire by Type
@Resource  = wire by bean name